# Merging 2 Django projects

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to merge one Django project into another one but am having difficulties. My core and Tab A were the original and then I'm trying to port over Tab B with templates folder into my core. I changed the settings.py and urls.py within the core but when loading the page I still get an error of template not found. Is there something I am missing? thank you. Both of these websites work independently 100% I just removed the managed.py within tab B because there would have been a merge conflict and just added the contents within it into core.manage.py.

```
core
    manage.py
core
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
Tab A
        apps.py
        admin.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
Tab B
        templates
                 main.html
        apps.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
templates
        base.html
```

Comment: please paste full traceback for error

Answer (score -1):

I removed some python code within my html file to get it to work

Comment: That's not a useful answer.